# Find a Value in a Column & Copy the Contents of the Row to Row Below It

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a project i am working on. I am trying to find a certain value in Column A - once that value is found - move to Column B & copy the contents of Column B-N into the row below it - there are breaks or rows in the data and it only seems to be "finding down" until the first break in the data - would someone be able to help?

Thanks for the time - my current code is below:

```
Worksheets("Chg").Activate

Range("A5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Set FoundTheCell = Selection.Find(What:="'8/2020", After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If FoundTheCell Is Nothing Then
    MyMsg = "The column 'During' was not found." & vbCrLf
    GoTo err_subCopyLastRowandReplace
Else
    FoundTheCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate

lastrowchange = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlRight)).Select
    
lastrowchange.Offset(1).Formula = lastrowchange.Formula
    
End If

exit_subCopyLastRowandReplace:
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
        
        
err_subCopyLastRowandReplace:
MyMsg = MyMsg & "Errored out in subCopyLastRowandReplace" & vbCrLf
MyMsg = MyMsg & "Error was: " & Err.Description
MsgBox MyMsg, vbOKOnly, MyTitle
Resume exit_subCopyLastRowandReplace
```

Comment: What is and what isn't working in your code? As in, what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: The code runs but it is only searching column A until the first break in the data in Column A(there are several blank rows) - I need it search down all of Column A, or at least until row 60 find the value '8/2020, copy the values in the row of data where '8/2020 is from B-N, and copy/paste it into the row below it wit the formulas - it returns my error message that the value is not found. Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of `End(xlDown))` you could try searching from the bottom up instead. This should avoid problems with blank rows. It's also best to avoid selecting things when not needed. Still, to not change everything at once, you could use something like `Range(Range("A5"), Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)).Select` to select from `A5` and all the way down.

Comment: Thanks for the response - the code is now doing the same thing from the bottom up - it is being stopped at the first break again - is there a way to just search A1-A60 where the breaks will be ignored?

Comment: Like `Range("A1:A60").Select`?

Comment: Still isnt wokring - its searching the range but just not working - i appreciate the help though.

Comment: What if you change your what to `What:="8/2020"` dose that make any difference?

Comment: Tried that already - it didnt work either - and the actual value in Col A is '8/2020 which is why i used that - thanks.

Comment: Try with another piece of text as a test, your search seemed to work for me. But the code has other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes and see if they work for you. I've done away with any selections or activations, and changed a few things around that were throwing errors for me.

Note that this will only apply to the first entry of `8/2020`.

```
Sub test()
Dim SearchRange As Range, FoundTheCell As Range, ws As Worksheet, lCol As Long, MyMsg As String, MyTitle As String
Set ws = Worksheets("Chg")
Set SearchRange = ws.Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
Set FoundTheCell = SearchRange.Find(What:="8/2020")

If FoundTheCell Is Nothing Then
    MyMsg = "The column 'During' was not found." & vbCrLf
    GoTo err_subCopyLastRowandReplace
Else
    lCol = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Range(FoundTheCell.Offset(1, 1), FoundTheCell.Offset(1, lCol - 1)).Formula = Range(FoundTheCell.Offset(, 1), FoundTheCell.Offset(, lCol - 1)).Formula 
End If

exit_subCopyLastRowandReplace:
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
        
        
err_subCopyLastRowandReplace:
MyMsg = MyMsg & "Errored out in subCopyLastRowandReplace" & vbCrLf
MyMsg = MyMsg & "Error was: " & Err.Description
MsgBox MyMsg, vbOKOnly, MyTitle
GoTo exit_subCopyLastRowandReplace

End Sub
```